# Weka -- Download the csv form

Tags: weka

When I tried to open Twitter.csv in Weka, I get an [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zzcgh.png) that the "attribute names are not unique".
Does anyone know how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be of unique name of the attributes. Please, remove prohibited characters.

Also please refer 
[Weka csv to arff special characters caue error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24399151/weka-csv-to-arff-special-characters-caue-error)

For Invoking a CSVLoader to open CSV File In the WEKA Workbench:

```
Open File > Open > Select 'invoke options dialog' > Select the file and Open > Opens weka.gui.GenericObjectEditor with weka.core.converters.CSVLoader
```

Fill-up required options for attributes like numeric, nominal, string, missing values, date etc. Which should work.

However, if still problem persists you need to check any errors in the lines in CSV using NotePad++ or Excel rectify errors in delimiters, attribute type, etc. 
manually with lot of care. This should rectify the problems.

If not check the validity of CSV file with available online or desktop tools.